# Different navbar depending on what role the user is

Tags: php, html

in my website I have 3 different roles. 1 (admin), 2(useradmin) and 3(user). When I log in now i come to 3 different type of sites, depending on what role the user has. But he navbar doesn't change. How do I do this (go easy on me if this is obvious, Im new to this).

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav">





END;

if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) /* Här är det userID */
  $navigation .= <<<END
<p class="inloggadsom"><b>{$_SESSION['fname']}</b> du är inloggad!</p>

    <li><a href="logout.php">Logga ut</a></li>
     <li><a href="admin.php">Generera licenser</a></li>


END;
else{
  $navigation .= ' <li><a href="index.php">Logga in</a></li> ';
  $navigation .= ' <li><a href="register.php">Beställ utbildning</a></li> ';
  $navigation .= ' <li><a href="lightutbildning.php">Light-utbildning</a></li>';
}
 $navigation .= ' </ul>
                  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                  <h2 class="slogan">Alltid, tryggt och nära!</h2>
                  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                  </nav> ';   

?>
```

this is the currents code, I have not done this, it's a classmate, but now it's my turn to take over from here.

The only thing that changes is the layout on the navbar, depending on if you are logged in or not.

Thanks in regards

Comment: Well, aren't you the one suppose to figure this out?

Comment: I kind of am, thats why Im asking here for tips :)  clever uh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the user-role in the database and then get it into the page (perhaps using the session details from the log in process) and depending on the value of that - echo different urls into the hrefs / different text into the link text. Or even have different li's for each role.

for example (if $userRole is the variable that determines the role of the user):

```
if($userRole=="admin"){$navigation .= ' <li><a href="admin.php">admin</a></li>'}
```

which will then only put that li into the ul if the userRole is"admin".